# GDB does not recognize Rust sources

Tags: rust, gdb

I would like to know what should be added into Cargo.toml to enable support of sources in gdb. Right now it contains the following:

```
[profile.dev]
debug = true
opt-level = 0
```

But it seems to be not enough. 
`gdb` command `list` displays nothing.
typing `directory ./src` does not help.

**UPD:**
I am used to gdb's tui. And it does not show the source code. But gdb without tui shows `list` properly. Why is it so strange?

Comment: What version of gdb you use? There is too old gdb version on some os. Try to build gdb from sources.

Comment: GNU gdb 8.1.0.20180409-git

Comment: My gdb works same as you: `list` command displays nothing in tui mode.

Comment: And the top view-block is also empty, isn't it?

Comment: I know GDB, but not rust. I created a simple project following the instructions here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.4.0/book/hello-cargo.html, built it and then ran GDB.  I can see source with and without tui.  Would you be able to create a more complete example project that shows the issue you are having and post it somewhere that others can access.